# Get Tier Price of Configurable Products that contain simple products : Magento 2.3

Tags: product, configurable-product, magento2.3.2, tiered-pricing

Currently, I am using the following code in `addtocart.phtml` to retrieve tier price data:

```
$allTiers     = $_product->getTierPrice();
$checktiers   = array_values($allTiers);
$tierPrices   = json_encode($checktiers);
```

This only works for simple products and not configurable products that contain simple products. The output on the configurable products always return `empty` array.

How can I retrieve tier price data from a configurable product that contains multiple simple products?

Any help?

Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Hey, did you solve this?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer : For my requirement, I have to override this file vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js in my theme.